# trying to delete multiple records in php page

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying below code for deleting multiple records from database. but when i open **users1.php** , i got  below result

[image]

**users1.php** - **javascript code** below is javscript code....

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteConfirm(){
    var result = confirm("Are you sure to delete users?");
    if(result){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select_all').on('click',function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $('.checkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = true;
            });
        }else{
             $('.checkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });

    $('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
        if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
            $('#select_all').prop('checked',true);
        }else{
            $('#select_all').prop('checked',false);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**users1.php - php code** - below is php code....

```
<?php
    include_once('dbcontroller.php');
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id, UserName, Type, department FROM Admin_Master";);
?>

<form name="bulk_action_form" action="users2.php" method="post" onsubmit="return deleteConfirm();"/>
    <table class="bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" value=""/></th>        
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Department</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
            if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="checked_id[]" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/></td>        
            <td><?php echo $row['UserName']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Type']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['department']; ?></td>

        </tr> 
        <?php } }else{ ?>
            <tr><td colspan="5">No records found.</td></tr> 
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="bulk_delete_submit" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

Please let me know if you need more information....

Comment: check what are you getting into this : `$query = mysqli_query($conn, $yourquery);
if(! $result) {
    die("SQL Error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}`

Comment: @prakashtank sorry, please check answer.....

Comment: Funny; I didn't see a `DELETE FROM .............`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove semicolon in mysqli_query()

$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id, UserName, Type, department FROM Admin_Master";);

Comment: sorry for that , yes i got before few seconds and posted an answer.....